# WP8.1 Silverlight App Ads, Obj ref not set to instance

Tags: vb.net, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, ads

I have an adcontrol on my WP8.1 Silverlight App. Whenever the app goes into landscape, I get the following error, captured in the adcontrol's "erroroccured" event. If my phone starts the app and the phone is in the portrait up position, this error does not occur, but if I turn my phone, after my items are repositioned, I get the error(Object reference not set to an instance of object).

P.S. I am currently using this test unit:            Image300_50, test_client

```
Start Error------
   at Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdvertisingWebBrowser..ctor(Double controlWidth, Double controlHeight, Boolean isClickable, Boolean showProgressBar, WebBrowserPool objectPool)
   at Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdvertisingWebBrowser..ctor(Double controlWidth, Double controlHeight, String html, WebBrowserPool objectPool)
   at Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.BannerAdFrameManager..ctor(BannerAd ad, Int32 adWidth, Int32 adHeight, Size maxSize, StackPanel parent, WebBrowserPool objectPool)
   at Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdFrameManager.CreateAdFrameManager(IAdvertisement ad, StackPanel parent, EventHandler`1 richMediaActionEventHandler, Thickness expandedAdMarginPx, String rendererOptions, Double width, Double height, Double scale, Size maxSize, EventBroadcaster eventBroadcaster, WebBrowserPool objectPool)
   at Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdControl.VerifyAndDisplayAd(IAdvertisement ad)
   at Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdControl.RefreshAdInternal()
End Error-------
```

Comment: No. Workaround=Start new app, don't place ad control on canvas, instead place on grid.

Comment: this is a simply project. but not it works. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26312884/TestApp.zip